# How to set video duration using python?

Tags: python, ffmpeg, video-streaming

I write a python program to record streaming video. I can play the recorded video using VLC. I find the duration will be 1 hour whatever how much time I take to record the video.

Here is the code snippet:

```
f = open(filename, 'wb')
block_size = 1024
duration = 2 * 60 # 2 mins

start = datetime.now()
end = start + timedelta(seconds=duration)

while datetime.now() < end:
    try:
        buffer = response.read(block_size)
        if not buffer:
            break

        f.write(buffer)

    except:
       pass 

f.close()
```

I use ffmpeg to inspect the video. It tells me 1 hour of duration.

So is there a way to set the correct duration for the streaming video recording?

The medata data for the video inspected by ffmpeg
[image]

Comment: There is not much we can do without seeing any of your code and without further information from you detailing exactly what you are doing.

Answer (score 0):

I can give you a better answer if you add a little code for context. But as is, all I can recommend is that you make it stream indefinitely and have the user on the other end manually terminate the stream.

If your program throws an error once the video is over, even better. A simple error handler can take care of ending the stream.

Comment: The program saves video and exits after certain amount of time. I have add code. Please have a look.

Comment: @shoujs Actually, the code you already have should work for this. If you want to, you could have the duration var set outside the code as a global, or make this code a method and have the duration as an argument.